# Applying CSS animations to a square(dynamically changing the border size and square size)

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, css-selectors

The screenshot [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqDXi.png) explains everything about the desired effect. I was thinking to decrease the border width from 4px to 3px to 2px , I don't want to apply ease-in/ease out effect. As of now, when I hover, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd3eQ.png). I want to change this box through the effect displayed in the first screenshot.

For reference, 
I am posting the code below:

```
&__link {
    @include font-text(default, menuitem);
    @include token(font-size, sidenav, default);
    background-image: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 1rem;
    margin: 0;

    &:before {
      position: absolute;
      right: 1.3rem;
      top: 2rem;
      width: 1px;
      content: '';
      background: #fff;
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 0.3;
    }

    &:after {
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: middle;
      position: relative;
      content: '';
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      outline: 1px solid #fff;
      top: -1px;
    }

    &:hover {
      @include font-text(default, menuitem);
      @include token(font-size, sidenav, hover);
      font-weight: 600;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 1rem;

      &:after {
        background: white;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
      }
    }
  }
```

&:after represents the code for the box. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="box">
</div>

.box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: white;
  background-image: linear-gradient(#000, #000);
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% 0%;
  transition: .5s;
}
.box:hover {
  background-size: 95% 95%;
}
```

Didnt understand the question too well but this does the attached screenshot animation

Answer (score 0):

> Try it - you need to set animations, bcz you want several situations for single event (hover)

**Replace these blocks**

> ```
> &:after {
>   display: inline-block;
>   vertical-align: middle;
>   position: relative;
>   content: '';
>   width: 0px;
>   height: 0px;
>   top: -1px;
>   background: white;
>   border: 7px solid #fff;
> }
>
> &:hover:after {
>     animation: sqr .3s linear;
>     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
>   }
>
>
> @keyframes sqr {
> 30%{
> border: 5.5px solid #fff;
> width: 3px;    height: 3px;    
> background: black;
> }   
> 80%{   
> border: 4px solid #fff;    
> width: 6px;    
> height: 6px;    
> background: black;
> } 
> 100%{    
> border: 3px solid #fff;    
> width: 8px;   
> height: 8px;    
> transform: scale(1.5);    
> box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px #fff;    
> background: black;  
> }  
> }
> ```

Comment: That you. This is exactly what I was looking for.